# Master Page Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to build multiple layouts in which everyone has a common part (a sidebar with several buttons). That is, static sidebar on the left side and right side dynamic content that changes according to the click of the buttons on the static menu.

I have tried and failed with fragements. Does anyone know of a solution to my problem?

Thanks

Kiotto

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121986/button-onclick-listener-in-included-layouts. Hope this may help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2011/01/08/ldquomaster-pagesrdquo-in-android.aspx) article is what you need.
I know that only posting an URL is not a good way to answer, but did not have time to fill in all the details at the moment.