# Common class for click listener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-button

I have 7 buttons in all my 6 activities. All 6 buttons have the same functionality in all activities. How can I perform a common click event lisnter for these 6 buttons.

Comment: what is that common task?

Comment: Whatever it could be. Displaying Toast for All buttons.

Answer (score 13):

You can create a new class that implements View.OnClickListener like this:

```
public class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         // TODO handle the click   
    }
}
```

In all your activities you can then set the click listener like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener());
```

You could even save the context in the class for displaying Toasts etc.

```
public class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Context context;

    public MyClickListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         Button button = (Button) view;
         Toast.makeText(this.context, button.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow.. what a simple solution. I wonder why you had not got any +1 up till now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have a class like this:

```
public class OnClickMaker{
    public static View.OnClickListener getOnClick(){
         return new View.OnClickListener(){
              public void on click(View v){
                  //do stuff
              }
          };
    }
}
```

And then in your other class, do this

```
button.setOnClickListener(OnClickMaker.getOnClick());
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting more words in Sagar's answer given above.

### Assumption:

As you have said you have 7 buttons in your 6 activities, I assume all the 7 buttons have same functionality/code.

### Solution:

**Step 1:** Include `android:click="btnFirstClick"` in `<Button>` inside your XML layouts.

**Step 2:** Define abstract BaseActivity class by extending Activity and include methods with the same name you have given in `android:onClick` attribute.

```
abstract public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

   public void btnFirstClick(View v) {
   }

   public void btnSecondClick(View v) {
   }

   .....
   .....
  // same for other buttons
}
```

**Step 3:** Now extends this BaseActivity to all your 6 activities.

For example:

```
public class FirstActivity extends BaseActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
           setContentView(R.layout.layout_first);
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I am inflating buttons layout in all Activities. So in that case how can I do.

Comment: @URAndroid Thank you for wasting all of us time!!

Answer (score 0):

Make a Function in a Class and put that class in the same package where all other classes are there. Simply just call that function in 6 onclicklisteners .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

Put the click events in the XML files `android:click="clickMe"`

Create this function in a `Activity` say

```
public void clickMe(View view) {
...//You handling code
}
```

and extend this Activity by all your activities.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am inflating buttons layout in all Activities. So in that case how can I do that.

Comment: Keep the button's layout file as a separate xml layout file and include that in all your activity layouts. This will also give a advantage of code reuse and easy modifiability.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like following

create a base activity

```
class BaseActivity extends Activity{
    public void onSpecificEvent(View v){
        // do your tasks
    }
}
```

now extends your activities from this one

```
class Activity1 extends BaseActivity
class Activity2 extends BaseActivity
```

In which buttons you need to implement the onClick use following in xml

```
android:onClick="onSpecificEvent"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the same situation like me, I have a linear layout with undetermined number of buttons in it (generated dynamically) and you want a common listener for all of the button (log out their text for example), you can do like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        final Button b = (Button) linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Commons.log(b.getText().toString());
                //your other code here
            }
        });
    }
```

Now all the children (buttons) of the linear layout have same click listener